# How can I prevent duplicate information from entering the mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

In this program I created a database called mydata and I created a table called mining and I wanted to read my name and last name and age from a list in  and if it was not in the database, save it in the database . But I got into trouble and my program gives an error.

In fact, in writing SQL syntax, it would store the data in the database if it did not exist. I have a problem

mycode:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx  = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '',
    database = 'mydata'
)

c = cnx.cursor()

list_number = ['mobin','ghanbari',15]


for i in list_number:
    c.execute('INSERT INTO mining VALUES ("%s","%s","%s") WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mining)'%(i,i,i))
```

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: Make the column that you don't want any duplicates in [unique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp).

Comment: There is already information in the database.I mean that if the information in the list is not in the database, it should be added to the database.

Comment: You should send a query to the database to insert it, and if the return value is not `true`, that means that either the query is wrong or a unique column already has the value.  Otherwise it will be inserted.  I'm sorry if I don't understand your question.

Comment: Please put your answer in the answer section. Thanks

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add unique index for the fields you do not want duplicate

Here an example with 3 fields . You can with multiple fields

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mining ADD UNIQUE INDEX(your_field1, your_field2,your_field3);
```

And use INSERT IGNORE instead of INSERT . This prevent query to insert same data two or more times in the table

```
for i in list_number:
    c.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO mining VALUES ("%s","%s","%s") )
```

Or execute a query:

```
SELECT * FROM mining WHERE 
your_field1 = 'mobin' AND 
your_field2 = 'ghanbari' AND 
your_field3 = 15;
```

Before the query INSERT .

if the SELECT query return something do not execute the INSERT query. Otherwise do the INSERT query.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. I'm just saying how can I enter non-duplicate information in the database. Your solutions did not work

Comment: I will try to be as clear and detailed as possible in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the columns you don't want duplicate information in unique.  This way, when you try putting duplicate information in them, SQL will send a failure message to you in Python.

For example, take this table:

| username (unique) | password |
| --- | --- |
| myusername | mypassword |

When you try adding `[newusername,newpassword]`, it won't give any error.

| username (unique) | password |
| --- | --- |
| myusername | mypassword |
| newusername | newpassword |

If we insert `[anotherusername,mypassword]`, it won't give an error because `password` isn't unique

| username (unique) | password |
| --- | --- |
| myusername | mypassword |
| newusername | newpassword |
| anotherusername | mypassword |

But when we try inserting `[myusername,anotherpassword]`, SQL will return an error to Python saying that since the `username` column is unique, it wasn't able to insert duplicate data (`myusername` is duplicate).

| username (unique) | password |
| --- | --- |
| myusername | mypassword |
| newusername | newpassword |
| anotherusername | mypassword |

See [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) to learn how to make a column unique.

Answer (score 0):

Access to mysql

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Creating Database and table as example on mysql from command line.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE sof;
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> use sof;
```

Database changed

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE mining (
    -> id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -> firstname varchar(255),
    -> age int,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------+
| Tables_in_sof |
+---------------+
| mining        |
+---------------+

mysql> explain mining;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lastname  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| firstname | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| age       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE mining ADD UNIQUE INDEX(firstname, lastname, age);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM mining;
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+ 
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | 
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+ 
| mining |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | 
| mining |          0 | firstname |            1 | firstname   | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | 
| mining |          0 | firstname |            2 | lastname    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | 
| mining |          0 | firstname |            3 | age         | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |                     
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+                     
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note the field `Non_unique`
1 if the index can contain duplicates, 0 if it cannot.

**Now the Python Script:**

```
import mysql.connector

mydb  = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '',
    database = 'sof'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

listd =[
    {'firstname':'mobin1','lastname':'ghanbari1','age':15},
    {'firstname':'mobin2','lastname':'ghanbari2','age':16},
    {'firstname':'mobin3','lastname':'ghanbari3','age':17},
    {'firstname':'mobin4','lastname':'ghanbari4','age':18}
]

for row in listd:
    sql = "INSERT INTO mining (firstname, lastname , age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (row['firstname'],row['lastname'], row['age'])

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted for "+row["firstname"])
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("mysql exception: {}".format(err))
        print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted for "+row["firstname"])
```

Output:

```
1 record inserted for mobin1
1 record inserted for mobin2
1 record inserted for mobin3
1 record inserted for mobin4
```

**Checking on mysql if records was inserted**

```
mysql> select * from mining;
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
| id | lastname  | firstname | age  |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
|  1 | ghanbari1 | mobin1    |   15 |
|  2 | ghanbari2 | mobin2    |   16 |
|  3 | ghanbari3 | mobin3    |   17 |
|  4 | ghanbari4 | mobin4    |   18 |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+


4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Adding some data in the list of Python script***

```
import mysql.connector

mydb  = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '',
    database = 'sof'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

listd =[
    {'firstname':'mobin1','lastname':'ghanbari1','age':15},
    {'firstname':'mobin2','lastname':'ghanbari2','age':16},
    {'firstname':'mobin3','lastname':'ghanbari3','age':17},
    {'firstname':'mobin4','lastname':'ghanbari4','age':18},    
    {'firstname':'mobin5','lastname':'ghanbari5','age':19},
    {'firstname':'mobin6','lastname':'ghanbari6','age':20},
    {'firstname':'mobin7','lastname':'ghanbari7','age':21}
]

for row in listd:
    sql = "INSERT INTO mining (firstname, lastname , age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (row['firstname'],row['lastname'], row['age'])

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted for "+row["firstname"])
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("mysql exception: {}".format(err))
        print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted for "+row["firstname"])
```

**Running the Python Script**

**Output:**

```
mysql exception: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'mobin1-ghanbari1-15' for key 'firstname'
-1 record inserted for mobin1
mysql exception: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'mobin2-ghanbari2-16' for key 'firstname'
-1 record inserted for mobin2
mysql exception: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'mobin3-ghanbari3-17' for key 'firstname'
-1 record inserted for mobin3
mysql exception: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'mobin4-ghanbari4-18' for key 'firstname'
-1 record inserted for mobin4
1 record inserted for mobin5
1 record inserted for mobin6
1 record inserted for mobin7
```

**Checking on mysql if we have duplicate entries**

```
mysql> select * from mining;
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
| id | lastname  | firstname | age  |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
|  1 | ghanbari1 | mobin1    |   15 |
|  2 | ghanbari2 | mobin2    |   16 |
|  3 | ghanbari3 | mobin3    |   17 |
|  4 | ghanbari4 | mobin4    |   18 |
| 13 | ghanbari5 | mobin5    |   19 |
| 14 | ghanbari6 | mobin6    |   20 |
| 15 | ghanbari7 | mobin7    |   21 |
+----+-----------+-----------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see  there are no duplicate entries in the table.